# Word for 'advanced'/'mastered'/'learned'/'technical'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which encompases the idea of techinal skill, experience, style, creativity and mastery in the context of writing. In particular in reference to sentence and paragraph structure.

For instance, in the following sentence:

"while most high-schoolers' essays follow the prescriptive 'Point Evidence Explanation' structure, her essay was, stylistically, much more ..."

Comment: On my handheld, so I can't provide an "expert answer" at present, but a couple words come to mind.  Consider **nuanced** or **masterful.** https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/amp/english/masterful

Comment: I'm thinking she's a virtuosa at writing. There's the adjective virtuosic. Virtuoso mostly is used with musicians, but can be used with other arts. Wikipedia: "More commonly applied in the context of the fine arts, the term can also refer to a 'master' or 'ace' who excels technically within any particular field or area of human knowledge"  American Heritage Dictionary: 2. A person with masterly skill or technique in the arts.

Comment: Please tell us which words from the thesaurus you have considered  but discarded, as well as why they were not working for you. Otherwise this is just a writing request, a thesaurus question with voting. It looks like you are looking for an adjective not a noun, but it is hard to tell.

Comment: Can you please provide words which you think are not suitable to represent your thoughts? It will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have listed multiple attributes of writing skills. If you want to describe all the qualities at the same time: *technical skill, experience, style, creativity and mastery in the context of writing*, then you can use combination of *adj.* + *noun* to describe all these attributes.

> *Eloquent* (adjective) [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eloquent) : Fluent or persuasive in speaking or **writing**.
>
> *Wordsmith* (noun) [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wordsmith) : a person who works with words; especially : a **skillful writer**.

Your sentence:

> while most high-schoolers' essays follow the prescriptive 'Point Evidence Explanation' structure, her essay was, stylistically, much more like **an eloquent wordsmith**.

There are nearly [300](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22eloquent%20wordsmith%22) entries of *eloquent wordsmith* in Google Books.

Answer (score 0):

**maven**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/maven) chiefly AmE

> A person who has special knowledge or experience; an expert.

As in a **literary mavens**: sentence examples from [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/115216?redirectedFrom=maven#eid).

1969  Time

> Much of the credit for the Cinderella publishing story goes to Robert
>   Gottlieb, then the editorial genie in residence at Simon & Schuster,
>   now the **maven** at Alfred Knopf.

1985   Maledicta

> I don't think your project is exactly the answer to a dictionary
>   **maven's** prayer.

1991   Eng. Today

> I have in mind such English language **mavens** as William Safire and
>   Robert MacNeil.